# How do you add a jquery library?

Tags: jquery

Got a piece of code that is working on fiddle but i don't think my library is correct. or i haven't done the below right

im really lost as what to do can someone link me a jquery library

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main Form</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="CSS/Stylesheet.css">
    <script src="Jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Do you have Jquery in the same folder?

Comment: Have you tried google? http://tinyurl.com/pzrzjr2

Comment: Yeah im really struggling to understand why it isnt working, this is my code that im trying to implement http://jsfiddle.net/AFfa2/

Comment: what is not working ...your fiddle works fine

Comment: i cant get that fiddle to work on the webpage the button just does nothing

Answer (score 1):

You neeed to add your script file paths like

```
<script src="http://localhost/myfolder/jsfolder/Jquery.js"></script>
```

loclahost will be either your `IP` and myfolder will be your main project folder we can say and jsfolder be the folder at which you will store the js files incliduing this `Jquery.js`

You can also use `SERVER` variables.And some of the js that we can add them directly like

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will include `Jquery.min.js` file directly from `googleapis.com`

Comment: Its in the same folder though? Does that make <script src="Jquery.js"></script> alright?

Comment: Yes you can but in that case you need to maintain both the js file and your file where you are including it in same folder.But you have to use entire file path for your further use

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a JQuery library... here you go

http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a CDN hosted jQuery library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use google hosted library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="/jsfolder/jQuery.js"></script>
```

http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

**Find here :**

Google Hosted Libraries - Developer's Guide

> https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

**Example :**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/your.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Google snippets:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use `jquery CDN`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

or u can just download the `jquery-1.10.1.min.js` file add it in your project
add add path of this file in your project

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DesktopModules/DMS/DMS.PatientEChart/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```