# Why isn't my javascript file linking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first time trying to make my jQuery code work somewhere other than codeacademy.com so bear with me please.

I've got three files, index.html, stylesheet.css and script.js (plus a few pictures) all in the same folder. index.html and style.css are playing well with eachother, but script.js doesn't seem to want to take any effect at all, no matter what I put in it (with commands as simple as hiding a paragraph upon $(document).ready...

Here's index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>test test test</p>
<div class="mainh1">
    <h1 id="header1">Hi I'm <a href="mailto:redacted@gmail.com" id="email">James</a></h1>
    <h1 id="header2">I live in <a href="www.seattle.gov" id="city">Seattle</a></h1>
    <h1 id="header3">I like <a href="www.makerhaus.com" id="tinker">tinkering</a></h1>
    <h1 id="header4">and I <em>really</em> like <a href="www.analogcoffee.com" id="coffee">coffee</a></h1>
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img src="james.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's stylesheet.css:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

body {
    background-image: url("debut_light.png");
}
.mainh1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Cantora One', sans-serif;
    color: #556270;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #fff;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    line-height: 150%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#email {
    color: #03738E;
}

#city {
    color: #F1B703;
}

#tinker {
    color: #F15B07;
}

#coffee {
    color: #D92D01;
}

.image {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's script.js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('p').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

I've also tried linking the entire source path for script.js and I've tried uploading it to a server on hostgator.com to no avail. Any idea why my jquery isn't working? If it's a simple mistake please bear with me, this is day 5 of coding for me.

Comment: First add Jquery js and then you script file. with out jquery js file it won't work.. file http://code.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: First thing to do is to open your console when javascript doesn't work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't loaded jQuery. Add this code before loading your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ha, nice way to get your first few rep on SO.

Comment: lol. Is this the same answer as your other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18508623/283863 but this one got like +6*10 = 60 reputation.

Comment: Thanks! And thank you to everyone else for the down-votes, my self-esteem is soaring :)

Comment: @user3176740 - At least you have two upvotes, which means 2*5-4*2 = +2 net total ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not linked the jQuery library to the html file. You will need it to be able to run jQuery functions such as `$(document).ready()`.

Have a look at [this page](http://jquery.com/download/) for different options on how to download jQuery or include it from a CDN.

Answer (score 1):

You  are using jquery without including it in your page.

You have to download jquery script file , rename it to jquery.js for example and include it.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Add this between  and  after downloading jquery and it will work.

Comment: There is [no `language` attribute in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) and you don't even need `type=""`...

Answer (score 0):

Go to jquery.com and download jQuery :)

http://jquery.com/download/